# Value not accessible after fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In SugarCRM 7.2.2 for validations, I have put following code to get Team and there users but the line var myTeamusers = userTeam2.getRelatedCollection('users'); is returning null. Strange thing is same code is working on Chrome console.

```
var userTeam2 = App.data.createBean('Teams',{id:'e8566565-0d27-2f09-edf5-  52c67c376d41'});//WORKING FINE
userTeam2.fetch();//WORKING FINE
var myTeamusers = userTeam2.getRelatedCollection('users');//WORKING FINE
myTeamusers.fetch({relate:true});//WORKING FINE
alert("two"+ myTeamusers); // HERE RETURING NO VALUE I.E. LENGTH OF TEAM IS 0 HERE BUT WHEN RUN ON CHROME CONSOLE SHOW IT 4 USERS IN TEAM
myTeamusers.toJSON();
alert("three"+ myTeamusers.toJSON());
alert("four"+ myTeamusers.toJSON().length);//SHOW IT 0
```

Please tell me what is wrong with above code, I have used above code at custom/modules/Cases/clients/base/views/record/record.js

Comment: Looks like asynchronicity problem, but we lack sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the `userTeam2` after the fetch is finished. Use the `success` callback:

```
userTeam2.fetch({
    success: function () {
        userTeam2.getRelatedCollection('users');
    }
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

Comment: Hello akoskm, Thanks for reply, I have run the code suggested by you, as mentioned below , but unable to get value -                      var userTeam2 = App.data.createBean('Teams',{id:'e8566565-0d27-2f09-edf5-52c67c376d41'});
userTeam2.fetch({
    success: function () {
       var myTeamusers = userTeam2.getRelatedCollection('users');
console.log("step1.o"+myTeamusers);
console.log("step1"+myTeamusers.fetch({relate:true}));
console.log("step1"+myTeamusers.fetch({relate:true}).length);
console.log("step2"+myTeamusers.toJSON());

}
})

Comment: Hello akoskm,Thanks but unable to get value -  var userTeam2 = App.data.createBean('Teams',{id:'e8566565-0d27-2f09-edf5-52c67c376d41'});
userTeam2.fetch({success: function () {var myTeamusers = userTeam2.getRelatedCollection('users');
console.log("step1.o"+myTeamusers);
console.log("step1"+myTeamusers.fetch({relate:true}));
console.log("step1"+myTeamusers.fetch({relate:true}).length);
console.log("step2"+myTeamusers.toJSON());}})OUTPUT step1.ocoll:Teams/e8566565-0d27-2f09-edf5-52c67c376d41/Users-0 components_9ed9e3a5c9873cf3fae060e8438012b1.js:479
step1[object Object] 
step1undefined 
step2

Comment: You have to be more specific. Create a jsfiddle example which demonstrates your problem.